# NextJS images not loading

Tags: reactjs, static, next.js

In my root project I have a /public holder set up with a "home.jpg" and "home-placeholder.jpg" image files.

Inside my /pages/index.js file I have a component that takes in two images:

```
function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head title="Home" />
      <Home>
        <Right
          alt="home-image"
          image="./home.jpg"
          placeholder="./home-placeholder.jpg"
        />
      </Home>
    </>
  );
}
```

I cannot get those images to display in my dev server, I always get: Cannot GET /home.jpg.

I've tried:

- using next-images and importing the images
- building and deploying on my production server
- changing name of public folder to /static/

The images are correctly loading inside the output path /.next/static/images/

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `.next` folder before running the dev server?

Comment: @Hangindev Thanks, I've tried it but no luck. The image path is "http://localhost:8000/home-placeholder.jpg" instead of the .next folder output. If you would like to see the repo it is here: https://github.com/sanderdebr/sleepdiary

Comment: I see that you are using custom server. I tried to start the dev server with `next dev` and the images are loaded correctly. So you probably need to do some settings in your custom server to serve static files I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using custom Express Server and you are missing Next app requestHandler:

```
import * as Routes from "~/src/routes";
import express from "express";
import next from "next";

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const app = next({ dev, quiet: false });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler(); // <----

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    return await Routes.signIn(req, res, app);
  });

  server.all("*", (req, res) => { // <----
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Check out this [Custom Express Server example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express) by Next.js.